# how to insert dynamic array value in database using php

Tags: php

**Below Dynamic Array:**

```
array (size=11)
  'reward_title' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'kishan' (length=6)
      1 => string 'kishan' (length=6)
  'amount' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '100' (length=3)
      1 => string '200' (length=3)
  'description' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'k' (length=1)
      1 => string 'kk' (length=2)
  'estimated_delivery' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '02/02/2017' (length=10)
      1 => string '02/03/2017' (length=10)
```

**Below Database Table Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

MY Question: how to insert dynamical array into my database table.please help me...........................................................................

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried already and provide some code, see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your queries like this:

```
//Helpers
$columns = array();
$values = array();
$parameters = array();
$itemCount = -1;

//Iterate array
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    //Parse columns and parameters
    $columns[]=$key;
    $parameters[]=":".$key;
    $values[$key] = $value;
    //We need the number of records to be inserted later
    if ($itemCount === -1) {
        $itemCount = count($value);
    }
}

//This is how the query will look like with the help of $columns and $parameters
$sql = "insert into yourtable(".implode(",", $columns).") values(".implode(",", $parameters).")";
//Iterate record indexes
for($index = 0; $index < $itemCount; $index++) {
    //We assume your PDO object is called $dbh and prepare the statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    //Iterate $column/$parameter indexes
    for($innerIndex = 0; $innerIndex < count($columns); $innerIndex++) {
        //and bind the parameters
        $stmt->bindParam($parameters[$innerIndex], $values[$columns[$innerIndex]][$index]);
    }
    //Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Code is untested, read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @kishankakadiya you need to tell me how did you try and how did your try fail. I do not own a crystal ball to locate your problem if you do not give me information. Also, we are not here to solve your problem but to help you solve your problem. You need to show some effort which can not be seen from your question (so someone down-voted it) and "please solve my problem" is not motivating at all.